# Angular JS URL encoding issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-encoding, urldecode

I am working on an AngularJS app and some pages the url contain arabic characters.

when I use `$locatoin.url('/ar/brand/علوم-الحاسب')`  it works great.
Now the url is :

```
/ar/brand/علوم-الحاسب
```

But when I refresh the page via browser reload button the url encoded and become `/ar/brand/%25D8%25B9%25D9%2584%25D9%2588%25D9%2585-%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25AD%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B3%25D8%25A8`

my questions:

1- Is this browser related issue, server related issue or Angular JS related issue?

2- How can I disable url encoding?

**Note:** I am using `ngRoute` module for routing.

**Note:** I am using Laravel framework as back-end API and the bootstrapping of Angular app is starting from `index.blade.php` file

Thanks in advance!